# can't access a web server using soap and wsdl

Tags: php, rest, soap, wsdl

I wrote the following code:

```
<?php



$url = "https://ops.isignmedia.com/iSign-ear-iSign-ejb/DownloadServices4?wsdl";


$client = new SoapClient($url);
$fcs = $client->__getFunctions();
var_dump($fcs);

$res = $client->downloadData(array('startDateTime' => 'null', 'endDateTime' => 'null','accountCode' => 'xxxx', 'userName' => 'xxxx', 'password' => 'xxxx'));




print_r($res);



?>
```

The error that I get is the following:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in /home/gsapte/public_html/grupsapte/test_webservice/isign.php:10 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('<?xml version="...', 'http://ip-172-3...', '', 1, 0) #1 /home/gsapte/public_html/grupsapte/test_webservice/isign.php(10): SoapClient->__call('downloadData', Array) #2 /home/gsapte/public_html/grupsapte/test_webservice/isign.php(10): SoapClient->downloadData(Array) #3 {main} thrown in /home/gsapte/public_html/grupsapte/test_webservice/isign.php on line 10
```

If I punt another wsdl address then using this method I can access all information I need. Question: what can be the reasons that I can't access that wsdl? can it be that is https instead of http?

Answer (score 1):

If you open this WSDL then on the bottom you will see:

```
<port binding="tns:DownloadWebServices4Binding" name="DownloadWebServices4Port">
    <soap:address location="http://ip-172-31-46-241.us-west-2.compute.internal:8080/iSign-ear-iSign-ejb/DownloadServices4"/>
</port>
```

This host might not be available. This is also visible in error message.

If you know other endpoint to this service try to use location or uri parameter to SoapClient.